# Scikit-learn custom estimator "Invalid parameter for estimator" error

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm implementing custom classifier for SVM ensemble with different voting schemes for my university project. My code for estimator:

```
svm_possible_args = {"C", "kernel", "degree", "gamma", "coef0", "shrinking", "probability", "tol", "cache_size",
                     "class_weight", "max_iter", "decision_function_shape", "break_ties"}

bagging_possible_args = {"n_estimators", "max_samples", "max_features", "bootstrap", "bootstrap_features",
                         "oob_score", "warm_start", "n_jobs"}

common_possible_args = {"random_state", "verbose"}


class SVMEnsemble(BaggingClassifier):
    def __init__(self, kernel="linear", voting_method=None, **kwargs):
        if voting_method not in {None, "hard", "soft"}:
            raise ValueError(f"voting_method {voting_method} is not recognized.")

        svm_args = dict()
        bagging_args = dict()
        for arg_name, arg_val in kwargs.items():
            if arg_name in svm_possible_args:
                svm_args[arg_name] = arg_val
            elif arg_name in bagging_possible_args:
                bagging_args[arg_name] = arg_val
            elif arg_name in common_possible_args:
                svm_args[arg_name] = arg_val
                bagging_args[arg_name] = arg_val
            else:
                raise ValueError(f"argument {voting_method} is not recognized.")

        probability = True if voting_method == "soft" else False
        svm_args = dict() if not svm_args else svm_args
        base_estimator = SVC(kernel=kernel, probability=probability, **svm_args)

        super().__init__(base_estimator=base_estimator, **bagging_args)
        self.voting_method = voting_method

    def predict(self, X):
        if self.voting_method in {None, "hard"}:
            return super().predict(X)
        elif self.voting_method == "soft":
            probabilities = np.zeros((X.shape[0], self.classes_.shape[0]))
            for estimator in self.estimators_:
                estimator_probabilities = estimator.predict_proba(X)
                probabilities += estimator_probabilities
            return self.classes_[probabilities.argmax(axis=1)]
        else:
            raise ValueError(f"voting_method {self.voting_method} is not recognized.")
```

I want to inherit most functionality from `BaggingClassifier` and plug in `SVC`. The user should be able to specify both SVM and bagging hyperparameters, so I've used for loop and `svm_possible_args` etc. to filter arguments passed to `SVC` and `BaggingClassifier`. The argument sets are almost separable (they only have `random_state` and `verbose` in common, which is not a problem).

I'm trying to find optimal hyperparameters with `GridSearchCV`:

```
def get_best_ensemble(X_train, y_train):
    parameters = {
        "voting_method": ["hard", "soft"],

        "max_samples": np.linspace(0.5, 1, 6, endpoint=True).round(1),
        "max_features": [0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1],
        "n_estimators": [5, 10, 15],

        "kernel": ["linear", "poly", "rbf", "sigmoid"],
        "C": [0.01, 0.1, 0.5, 1, 10],
        "gamma": [0.01, 0.1, 0.3, 0.6, 1]
    }

    model = SVMEnsemble()
    grid = GridSearchCV(model, parameters, verbose=2, cv=5, n_jobs=-1)
    grid.fit(X_train, y_train)

    print("Best hyperparameters:")
    print(grid.best_params_)

    return grid.best_estimator_
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
ValueError: Invalid parameter C for estimator SVMEnsemble(kernel=None, voting_method=None). Check the list of available parameters with `estimator.get_params().keys()`.
```

Using `print(model.get_params().keys())` I get `dict_keys(['kernel', 'voting_method'])`. Does that mean that I have to list **all** parameters for `SVC` and `BaggingClassifier` explicitly in my `__init__` for `SVMEnsemble` for `GridSearchCV` to be able to "see" them and actually work? Or is there any cleaner solution?

Comment: Do you have to implement a SVM ensemble yourself or can you just use sklearn? What you're trying to do seems redundant as you can already make a SVM ensemble with BaggingClassifier, just specify the base_estimator to be a SVC.

Comment: @BlueSkyz I kinda have to, it's for university project and it was forced on me. Besides, after all it was easier to do it this way for GridSearchCV optimization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could override the `get_params` and `set_params` methods, or have the actual SVM object as an initialization parameter.  You'll need to do something so that when the grid search tries to `set_params`, the `estimator` inside your instance gets updated correctly (not just the parameters in your instance; note that `__init__` doesn't get rerun).

There's some discussion on making inherited class parameter discovery easier, but it's tricky, and wouldn't solve the second problem:
https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/13555

Comment: Thank you! This is probably the "right" way to do it. Finally I've just written explicitly those few hyperparameters that I had to optimize with GridSearchCV, but in general those overrides sound great.